Is Windows / Linux Dual Boot a scam?
I have searched for this topic a bit on the web without any success.
Is Windows Dual boot + Linux way worse than it is imagined ?
Installaed a dual bot linux mint on a windows 11 computer. THe main objective > Get away from the frequent windows 11 updates as many linux users. What happened : It seems that the windows keeps working on the background with dual boot as the hard disk keeps working hard even though no signal of it being from the linux mint - that I installed -
Does Windows keep updtaing or doing some tasks on the background even though you dual booted on a linux machine ? Ubuntu / Mint / Arch
Some Say that You should Enable the Fastboot on Windows or DIsable ( I personally have it idsabled ) but doesnt seem to be the main issue here.

Not sure if this is the right place to ask

Linux has just as many updates many that require a restart.

Thing is I dont see the Computer having a High DIsk Usage nor Linux mint using the resources. on the monitor of resources

I really think that windows update is working somehwo on the background

Windows Update by default will happen when the machine isn’t being used. Updates are only released once a week at most.

@John Hmm. thank you for the answer. But what do you mean by ' you wont escape updates with dual boot'. Does it mean that even If the computer is open on The Linux distro, the windows will update somewhoe ?

you got a virtual machine ?

@unkp - John means that Windows and Linux are both updated routinely, an operating system that isn’t running, cannot be updated.

You can check which programs/processes are using your storage devices even on Linux, for example using iotop. If you have a more specific question in this direction, you should create a new Super User question to ask about it.

Based on your question, it sounds like you are booted into Linux and that Windows is still working in the background.  That is NOT what is happening.  If you are truly dual booting, Windows is shutdown and is not doing anything at all.  It is physically incapable of doing anything, as it is not running.  Any activity that is happening is happening inside of your Linux installation.

I heard that you should activate FastBoot - so windows will hibernate.

Otherwise it may keep working somehow on the background

@unkp No.  Fastboot has to do with the BOOTING process.  Nothing happens if Windows is not booted.  Same goes for hibernate.  If Windows is hibernated, it is off and not running.

Ok, It is just wierd that I got a high DIsk usage even though it doesnt appear on the monitor of resources. The Hardk DIsk is making the same noise as it used to make when windows 11 update was happening taking over all my computer. Ok, thank you will see what I can do.

Your question isn’t about high risk usage. You asked if dual booting is some kind of a scam, its not, obviously.

If you are asking this because of something you hear, then you are starting out from the wrong place. Linux will power on the disk, and it will spin, but if you don't mount it as storage in linux, it won't be performing any actual IO.
